# Flutter page jumps to top after setState({})

Tags: flutter, dart

I display many images in a Staggered Gridview in a Flutter application.

Everytime I call `setState({})`, for example after deleting an item, the page jumps to top. How could I remove this behavior?

This is my code:

`final _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();`

.. outside the build function. And then...

```
return loadingScreen == true
  ? LoadingScreen()
  : Scaffold(
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          _AppBar(
            theme: theme,
            index: index,
            albumImagePath: albumImagePath,
            albumID: albumID,
            albumValue: albumValue,
            addPictureToGallery: _addPictureToGallery,
          ),
          SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                InfoBar(
                  albumPicturesSum: albumPicturesSum,
                  getBilderString: _getBilderString,
                  theme: theme,
                  getVideoProgress: _getVideoProgress,
                  progress: progress,
                ),
                albumID == 99999999
                    ? // Demo Projekt

                    DemoImageGrid(
                        demoImageList: demoImageList,
                        getDemoImagesJson: _getDemoImagesJson,
                      )
                    : UserImageGrid(
                        picturesData: picturesData,
                        albumID: albumID,
                        showPictureActions: _showPictureActions)
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
}
```

The `UserImageGrid` looks like the following:

```
class UserImageGrid extends StatelessWidget {
  final Pictures picturesData;
  final int albumID;
  final Function showPictureActions;
  final _key = new UniqueKey();

  UserImageGrid(
      {@required this.picturesData,
      @required this.albumID,
      @required this.showPictureActions});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
        key: _key,
        future: picturesData.getPicturesFromAlbum(albumID),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
          // Normale Projekte
          if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.length == 0) {
            return Center(
              child: Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Lottie.asset('assets/lottie/drone.json',
                      width: 250,
                      options: LottieOptions(enableMergePaths: false)),
                ],
              ),
            );
          }
          if (!snapshot.hasData ||
              snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          } else {
            return Container(
              child: StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                shrinkWrap: true,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                crossAxisCount: 6,
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) =>
                    GestureDetector(
                  onLongPress: () {
                    showPictureActions(snapshot.data[index]);
                  },
                  onTap: () async {
                    await showDialog(
                        context: context,
                        builder: (_) {
                          return Dialog(
                              child: Stack(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                                  vertical: 10.0,
                                  horizontal: 10.0,
                                ),
                                height: 500.0,
                                child: ClipRect(
                                  child: PhotoView(
                                      maxScale:
                                          PhotoViewComputedScale.covered * 2.0,
                                      minScale:
                                          PhotoViewComputedScale.contained *
                                              0.8,
                                      initialScale:
                                          PhotoViewComputedScale.covered,
                                      imageProvider: FileImage(
                                          File(snapshot.data[index].path))),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Positioned(
                                bottom: 20,
                                left: 20,
                                child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                  child: Text(
                                    DateFormat(tr("date_format")).format(
                                        snapshot.data[index].timestamp
                                            .toDateTime()),
                                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              )
                            ],
                          ));
                        });
                  },
                  child: Container(
                      child: Image.file(
                    File(snapshot.data[index].thumbPath),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  )),
                ),
                staggeredTileBuilder: (int index) =>
                    new StaggeredTile.count(2, index.isEven ? 2 : 2),
                mainAxisSpacing: 5.0,
                crossAxisSpacing: 5.0,
              ),
            );
          }
        });
  }
}
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: One possibility is that it's because a rebuild triggers a refresh of the FutureBuilder which causes the column to get repopulated. It's hard to say, though, since this isn't a [mcve], and with so much going on, it's tough for us to make anything more than educated guesses. On another note, your widget tree is massive. You should probably look into breaking that into more manageable pieces, which by itself would make it much easier to debug and see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for this issue. The problem was not the setState({}). It was the return Widget of the `FutureBuilder`.

I changed

```
if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
  return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
}
```

to:

```
if (!snapshot.hasData || snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
  return Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
  );
}
```

I don´t exactly know why, but with this change the page is not jumping to top anymore on `setState({})`